# Jsrasign, load public key into RSAKey()?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, public-key

I have a public key in pem format, I can't figure out how to encode it to load it into the `RSAKey()` object. The library offers 3 methods for public key reading: `readCertPubKeyHex, readPKCS5PubKeyHex, readPKCS8PubKeyHex` but I can't figure out how to encode the pem file for these methods, I've tried taking the base64 encode body of the pem file and converting to hexadecimal but end up with one of the following errors: `not ASN.1 hex string`, `not PKCS8 RSA public key` or `wrong hex for PKCS#5 public key`.

```
let rsa = new RSAKey();
rsa.readCertPubKeyHex("?? Ansi Hex ??");
let verified_config = rsa.verifyStringPSS(message, signature, "SHA512", 2);
```

I'm open to regenerating the public/private key pair if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was overlooking some very helpful utils to do this for you, the code should end up looking like:

```
let rsa = KEYUTIL.getKey("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----***yourPublicKeyHere-----END PUBLIC KEY-----");

let verified_config = rsa.verifyStringPSS(message, signature, "SHA512", 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting back Eric.